# How to import code in SML?

Tags: sml

I'm currently grading assignments for a course on SML. I've written some test cases to automatically check correctness of functions in the students' assignments, and I'd like to be able to import their code and then run the test cases against that code. I'm imagining something similar to python import semantics. Right now, the best solution I have is to copy-paste this code at the bottom of each assignment. Is this possible with SML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `use`:

```
use "filename.sml";
(* your test cases here *)
```

If you have the student solution in "student.sml" and your test cases in "tests.sml":

```
use "student.sml";
use "tests.sml";
```

Comment: Can you use the `use` function inside another SML file? I have tried and I always get an `operator is not a function` error.

Comment: rlandster, yes, you can have use in your SML files. It behaves as any other function.

Comment: Just as a note, ML implementations are not required to implement the `use` function.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [QCheck](http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/qcheck/), a unit testing library for SML