# How to compile multiple SML files?

Tags: sml, mosml

How does it work compiling multiple files in Standard-ML? I have 2 files.

`file1.sml`:

```
(* file1.sml *)
datatype fruit = Orange | Apple | None
```

And `file2.sml`:

```
(* file2.sml *)
datatype composite = Null | Some of fruit
```

So as you can see `file2.sml` is using stuff from `file1.sml`. How can I make this thing compile?

I am using `mosmlc.exe` and when compiling `mosmlc file2.sml` (as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845204/how-to-import-code-in-sml)):

```
(* file2.sml *)
use "file1.sml";
datatype composite = Null | Some of fruit
```

I get:

```
! use "file1.sml";
! ^^^
! Syntax error.
```

So, how to deal with multiple files?

Comment: It's useful to include the compiler complaint. Also, it's not clear whether you're using the `mosml` executable or the `mosmlc` one.

Comment: Just edited with those info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read more in [Moscow ML Owner’s Manual](http://mosml.org/manual.pdf), but in your particular case the following command should work without even having to use `use` in the source code:

```
mosmlc -toplevel file1.sml file2.sml
```

### Using Structure Mode

When you want to organize your code into structure, you can use the `-structure` flag of `mosmlc`. For example, given the following files:

#### Hello.sml

```
structure Hello =
  struct
    val hello = "Hello"
  end
```

#### World.sml

```
structure World =
  struct
    structure H = Hello

    val world = H.hello ^ ", World!"
  end
```

#### main.sml

```
fun main () =
  print (World.world ^ "\n")

val _ = main ()
```

You can now obtain an executable called `main`, like this:

```
mosmlc -structure Hello.sml World.sml -toplevel main.sml -o main
```

And then run it:

```
$ ./main
Hello, World!
```

Structure mode requires that you the name of the files and the contained structure coincide, just like in Java classes and files must have the same names. You can also use `.sig` files, which contain signatures.

Comment: I see... However can you also explain me how to incapsulate my code in these files and import into other files? I saw code where structures are defined and then opened in other files... in that case how does it work?

Comment: @Andry answer updated. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: Cool. I saw in some sources that they use `open <structure-name>`. When is it required?

Comment: @Andry `open Structure` is similar to `using Namespace` in C#. It makes all the members of that structure visible in the current scope. I'd recommend using the `structure Abbr = Abbreviation` approach, so that you know precisely what comes from where.

Comment: Man thank you. You made my day/night. Have a good day/night :)

Comment: @Andry sure! Same to you! :)